# How can I identify why entries disappear from Startup Applications?

Tags: startup, autostart

I have the problem that entries added to Startup Applications disappear upon reboot. They no longer exist there on restart.

**How can I identify why this is the case?**

- Might there be a limit to the number of entries?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that was answered in [Dropbox disappears from Startup Applications upon reboot in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984468/dropbox-disappears-from-startup-applications-upon-reboot-in-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1584993_984468). You may want to try the answer provided there by @JacobVlijm.

> Simply rename the file ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop to (e.g.) `start_dropbox.desktop` after it is created, and Dropbox will not recognize it as his, and leave the file alone.

In other words, when you add an entry to `Startup Applications`, a corresponding `.desktop` file is created in your `~/.config` folder (a hidden folder found in `Home` by typing `Ctrl + H` to show hidden files and folders). What worked in my case was renaming the file created there with anything (in my case changing it from `nameofapplication.desktop` to `start_nameofapplication.desktop`).

Answer (score 0):

Normally this issue will occur in Gnome upgrade case in Ubuntu 14:04. Try installing `ppa-purge`

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

and then running the below command and restart.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Note :  This will purge that PPA and replace all the applications that the PPA added with the Ubuntu defaults!

Comment: Thank you! Where do I get `ppa-purge` from? `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`

Comment: `Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: gnome3-team gnome3`